Simple HTML dom - get data
I have a problem with simple HTML Dom libraries.
I'm using simple HTML Dom in my PHP script and I want to get text from this HTML structure:
<div class="l_title">
  <h2 itemprop="name">
    <a href="/details.php">
      <span class="mdl">0005802314306</span>
      Ring
    </a>
  </h2>
</div>

When I use:
$html->find('div[class="l_title"] a',0)->plaintext;

I get full text from link. When I use:
$html->find('div[class="l_title"] a',0)->children(0)->plaintext;

I get text from span tag. How can I get a word Ring without span? children(1) not working. Any suggestion?
